# Mousepad stops working a few minutes after login (16.04)

Tags: touchpad, mousepad

I've only just installed Ubuntu yesterday (complete beginner in linux), and I'm having issues making my mousepad work. It works fine for a minute or two after starting up my laptop and logging in, but after that, the pointer moves very slowly and lags a lot, I can't tap to click, I can't scroll (neither two finger or edge scrolling). I've tried just about everything I've found on google about this, including

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/enabled_true

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
sudo update-grub

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

As well as creating a scrolling.sh file to startup that adds:

```
#!/bin/bash

synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

I just feel like I've tried everything and I just don't know enough about how linux works to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

Try this -> Go to recovery mode and update grub.  It can also be incompatible touch-pad drivers issue. It happened with me one time but after reinstalling grub it stared working in my case. I updated it with boot-repair disk at that time and using dual boot.

Comment: Recovery mode and updating grub didn't work. Tried reinstalling Ubuntu itself as well, didn't work either.

Comment: look for Linux drivers of your touch-pad and uninstall current  drivers.